# Regular expression for negativenumbers (123.456,789-)

Tags: regex

I'm searching for a pattern for matching numbers with hyphen at the end like this :

```
125,000-
1.234,567-
60,000-
```

Comment: Your decimal places example is a little ambiguous as it has 3 positions either side of the comma.  Should eg `1.234,5-` be valid, or should `1.2,345-` be valid?  My answer below covers each of those scenarios (and I believe, is more accurate than the others so far - which of course may be overkill for your scenario). Also, are the comma separators to the right of the decimal place mandatory, eg would `123,456.78901234-` also be valid?

Comment: @Sepster: In many european countries, the decimal separator is comma `,` and thousand separator is dot `.`

Comment: @M42 I assumed that in this case, the comma `,` was the thousand seperator, given the examples all had three places after _every_ comma.  But yes, given the OP is from France, you make a very good point thankyou!  I think therefore that I wasted a good deal of time coming up with my interpretation of what I _thought_ was required ;-)  Although simply swapping the comma and point positions in my answer would still do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
[0-9.,]+-
```

Comment: Works, Thank you djc, same for hsz and ales.

Comment: @Pepel Note that this also allows "invalid" values eg `,.,.-` or `,1.1.1-` which may or may not be restrictive enough for your purposes.

Comment: It also doesn't allow for non-western numbers.

Comment: **-1** for not providing a comprehensive regex

Answer (score 4):

Just try with following regex:

```
/\d[.,\d]*-/
```

Or even:

```
/\d([.,]?\d+)*-/
```

Comment: Note this also allows "invalid" values eg `1..1..1-` which may or may not be restrictive enough for OP purposes.

Comment: The second one doesn't allow `..`

Comment: But it does allow `1.1.1-` :-)

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE Aleš Krajník's answer is basically the same as the answer I *finally* came to, except that his uses non-capturing grouping (as captures are not required)... he should get the votes IMHO as he was first**

Note that in the following answer I'm assuming that `,` comma is the decimal separator, and that the `.` point is the thousands separator (eg for European numbering).

I believe the following is "correct":

`^\d{1,3}(.\d{3})*(,\d+)?-$`

This matches eg:

- 1-
- 12-
- 123-
- 123.456-
- 123.456.789-
- 1,0-
- 1,01-
- 1,001-
- 1,0001-
- 123.456,01-
- 123.456.789,0001-
- etc

But will not match eg

- 1234-
- 123,-
- 123.4-
- 123.1,001-
- 123.45-
- 1..1..1-
- 1.1.1-
- 1,1,1-
- .,-
- etc.

Comment: +1 for most complete answer.

Comment: @M42 Thanks mate.  Also just re-jigged it all to suit European numbering, and removed all separators right of the decimal separator, so now eg `123.456.789,00001-` is valid but `123.456.789,0.001` is not.

Comment: Is it not `(,\d+)?` to optionally allow "decimal comma plus at least one digit"? The current regex *will* match "123,".

Comment: @HansKesting Indeed you are correct, thanks so much for pointing that out.  Not sure how that got through my testing.  Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The exact regex should read: `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?-`

Comment: You might need to anchor that or something, as currently this will find a match eg `23-`_within_ eg `0.1.23-`.

Comment: Obviously, it depends on whether we want to match whole line / string, or we want to find numbers in string, that was not specified in the question.

Comment: Nothing's obvious in the world of regexes, hence the number of questions about regexes ;-)  I've just realised now that I've converted my answer to cater for European numbering (I had originally assumed `,` was a thousands separator) that my answer is more-or-less identical to yours - in fact, your's is _better_ as you're using non-capturing grouping... +1 and I'll reference your answer as better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

`\d{1,3}(?:[,]\d{3})*-` takes internationalisation into account. The one below allows strings like `1..9` to match, which really should not.

Comment: You might need to anchor that or something, as currently this will find a match eg `23-`_within_ eg `0.1.23-`.